# Error in building an archive in Xcode (I've used Unity & Firebase)

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine

I've been really struggling with this one.. for days now...
I've made an app using Unity (and Firebase), build an IOS build (without CocoaPods, so I've imported the frameworks later in the Xcode, has Firebase said in Step 4 here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks)
Till now, all good.
I've opened the .xcodeproj using Xcode, filled up my app's info, tried to build an archive and got this error:

```
ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: _unwind_tester from /Users/dor/Desktop/PullApp-1.0.0/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o)
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppApp.a(app_ios_814e1620d4f88024cea4bade26623a67.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRTransactionResult", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppDatabase.a(database_reference_ios_0c4ba7507f304dd9e420c9763efbc13d.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRDatabase", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppDatabase.a(database_ios_e51dee2718c2fa50bb12fbc46a002ec6.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRGameCenterAuthProvider", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppAuth.a(credential_ios_7e32949a14fe9694040ff5eed8d1b954.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GKLocalPlayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppAuth.a(credential_ios_7e32949a14fe9694040ff5eed8d1b954.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRGoogleAuthProvider", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppAuth.a(credential_ios_7e32949a14fe9694040ff5eed8d1b954.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRPhoneAuthProvider", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppAuth.a(credential_ios_7e32949a14fe9694040ff5eed8d1b954.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRPhoneAuthCredential", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppAuth.a(user_ios_1b162c7ca01af7914d8255750deffbf0.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIROptions", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppApp.a(app_ios_814e1620d4f88024cea4bade26623a67.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIROAuthProvider", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppAuth.a(credential_ios_7e32949a14fe9694040ff5eed8d1b954.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppApp.a(log_ios_dd26aec5b8537064a4c15d38b58b4640.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRFacebookAuthProvider", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppAuth.a(credential_ios_7e32949a14fe9694040ff5eed8d1b954.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRDatabaseReference", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppDatabase.a(database_reference_ios_0c4ba7507f304dd9e420c9763efbc13d.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIREmailAuthProvider", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppAuth.a(credential_ios_7e32949a14fe9694040ff5eed8d1b954.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRGitHubAuthProvider", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppAuth.a(credential_ios_7e32949a14fe9694040ff5eed8d1b954.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRTwitterAuthProvider", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppAuth.a(credential_ios_7e32949a14fe9694040ff5eed8d1b954.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAuth", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppAuth.a(auth_ios_b54468d60a10f4f18faae0e528a8c0ba.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What solutions did I try and still failed to make an archive?
- In the "other linkers" I've put "-ObjC".
- Changed the architectures to "standard architectures" (Don't know what it does but that's one of the many solutions my good friend google has recommended me).
- Made sure I've put the "-ObjC" both on the project's and the target's Build Settings (since this is repeatedly written in the error's message).

This^ is the solutions I was able to find online.. still nothing...
I could find anything really matching my exact error here on the website nor anywhere really...
Any ideas before I completely give up on IOS..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit - summarizing comments after this answer]

The issue is that the Unity SDK was out of date, see [this page](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity) for the latest version.

Also, you should be able to follow *just* the [Unity getting started instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup). The [iOS getting started instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) are only applicable for iOS native games and applications (the Unity SDK attempts to perform all the necessary actions through the included [External Dependency Manager for Unity](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver)).

[Original Answer]

I think I see what's happening here, note that the files that are missing all have Cpp in their name. The Unity SDK is built on top of the [C++ SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup?platform=ios) and you're missing all of those dependencies. These were included in the initial unitypackage you installed, so you might want to double check to make sure that you haven't accidentally deleted the `.a` files there (often times they're ignored as "build artifacts" by version control software).

With that in mind, unless you're doing something interesting with Firebase (ex: your own Unity bindings or maybe playing with embedding [Unity into an iOS app](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/06/17/add-features-powered-by-unity-to-native-mobile-apps/)) or just really really don't trust CocoaPods, you should let the External Dependency Manager for Unity handle resolving the iOS libraries. This ships with the Firebase Unity SDK, and should just work. I did a brief writeup [here](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-manage-your-native-ios-and-android-dependencies-in-unity-like-firebase-921659843aef?source=friends_link&sk=8db8be3ebd2b2e2452fb9ef440a9cf7a) (when it was still called the Play Services Resolver), and will hopefully clear up any uncertainties you have.

These are all my current (working) settings:
[image: Screenshot of my EDM4U iOS settings window]

Note with the way I've configured it, I need to open up the xcworkspace rather than the xcproj that you're used to. That is configurable via the `Cocoapods Integration` dropdown.

Let me know if you have any more questions!

--Patrick

Comment: First of all - THANK YOU SO SO SO MUCH !!! I'm stuck with implementing my app to IOS for over 14 days !! I have such a headache hahaha. Ok, so I've read all you've written (also the article, which was very insightful, so thanks again ^_^ ) and I've decided to go with your approach - with CocoaPods and the Resolver. So, I've created a new build from Unity, using your exact settings in the IOS Resolver. The build was successful (YAY) but, I also saw this error in the console: (in the next comment)

Comment: "iOS framework addition failed due to a CocoaPods installation failure. This will will likely result in an non-functional Xcode project.

After the failure, "pod repo update" was executed and succeeded. "pod install" was then attempted again, and still failed. This may be due to a broken CocoaPods installation. See: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html for potential solutions." (Countinue in the next comment)

Comment: "pod install output:

Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Analytics":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Analytics (= 5.15.0)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/Analytics (= 5.15.0)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile."

Comment: I've tried all the console's solutions, still nothing. I did notice something strange, I tried, few times, to modify the pods in the podfile and removed the version of each pod, and then I've tried to build the game again, but, the same exact error poped up, so i went to the podfile again, and saw that the pods versions were all back. something reseted it, but i don't know what and if it really matters.. hope you could help me, thanks again about everything, i do, really, appreciate it (^_^)

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. Is there a chance that you have different versions of the Firebase Unity SDKs installed? You can also try just wiping out your build directory and letting it regenerate. If you have success with _different_ versions of libraries in the Podfile, definitely report that to https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues. Generally you shouldn't touch the Podfile at all, and let the resolver do its thing. If you need new pods, creating a Dependencies.xml will ensure that your changes don't get erased (mentioned in that article I linked).

Comment: Is it possible to even have different SDKs installed? anyways, I'm deleting what I have now and re-insalling from firebase's website. Let's see what it does. For the other solutions: 1) I've already wiped the build directory. Multiple times. 2) What do you mean by "have success"? i mean, Unity says the build was successful, but at the same time that the build will probably fail on Xcode.. so.. yeah.

Comment: 3) Believe me I don't want to touch the Podfile either hahaha, but, what else could this error mean? : "CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Analytics": In Podfile: Firebase/Analytics (= 5.15.0) None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: Firebase/Analytics (= 5.15.0)"

Comment: 4) Yes, I saw you've mentioned the Dependencies.xml file, but I didn't quite understand something about it - I'm developing this app for Android also, and for that - it works perfectly. Just IOS makes me problems. So, if i will create this file, won't it overwrite or disturb in some way shape or form the already working Android dependencies?

Comment: Also, when I've searched online I found something called "External Dependency Manager for Unity (EDM4U)", could this maybe make my "Dependency Hell", well, less hellish? haha

Comment: So, EDM4U is what Firebase uses to resolve issues. If you have the latest SDK (6.13), it should already be in with files like `AppDependencies.xml` describing iOS and Android dependencies. I don't know CocoaPods well enough to know exactly what's happening, but it seems like somehow CocoaPods can't find Firebase/Analytics (https://cocoapods.org/pods/FirebaseAnalytics).

Comment: Looking at my own `AnalyticsDependencies.xml` I see the line `<iosPod name="Firebase/Analytics" version="6.17.0" minTargetSdk="8.0">`. You may just have an out of date SDK? Check here:
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity (also, update to my last comment, it looks like 6.14 is the latest)

Comment: Ok, appearantly i was using an old version of the SDK and the the build in Unity runs smooth hahaha Now, I'm trying to see if the pods part in Xcode will finally work. I have a question tho cause I'm a bit confused. In the Firebase docs there are 2 get started guides. One called "Add Firebase to your Unity project" and the other "Add Firebase to your iOS project", in my case, should i make sure i do both of them or just the Unity one? Cause form all the mess I'm not sure anymore if i need to install the pods myself, using "pod install" or not?..

Comment: Just the Unity one. In an ideal world, a Unity SDK would operate independent of the underlying operating system. Sometimes the abstraction breaks down, but for the most part you don't need to muck with any iOS or Android specifics.

Comment: Thank u SO MUCH Patrick !
Honestly, i'm a bit ashamed that my problem turned out to be an old version of the SDK.. But again, TRULY THANK YOU ! i really don't know what i would be doing.. I was stuck on this for over 2 weeks.. haha

Comment: If I'd followed normal support procedure, that should've been the first thing I asked about too. So it's partially on me . If you're ever stuck, feel free to reach out of https://firebase.community/ or https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk as well. I at least feel less pressure posting in slack than I do for formulating a whole SO post!

Answer (score 1):

This link helped me to solve issue: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-for-unity/issues/504.

But I had only one from your errors (Probably Firebase Problems):

**objc-class-ref in** **libFirebaseCppApp.a(app_ios_814e1620d4f88024cea4bade26623a67.o)**

which caused

> ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: _unwind_tester from
> /Users/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/YYYY/Build_iOS/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o)
> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "OBJC_CLASS$GKLocalPlayer"...

I manually added GameKit.framework with following steps :

UnityFramework (The one with yellow icon under your target) -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries (Scroll Till end and you will find the + button, press it and write in search "GameKit.framework")

[image]

Hope it helped someone, because I lost hours to find solution for this issue.